# Convert curl to python requests including cookies

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, cookiejar

Some background details:

We have an internal site which has SSO with 2FA, and also requires client certs.
It has a form which submits a job. I'm trying to automate the process by running it from CLI. So far I have been able to get a job submitted using curl. For it to work I need to extract the cookies from my browser session. So the following curl command is running as expected

`curl -b cookies.txt -k --cert cert --key key -F 'field=value' url`

I now tried to convert the same to a Python requests call. However it looks like it is not getting the cookies. I can see that from the output of script going to the SSO login page. Here is the script I have so far

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests
import http.cookiejar

cookies = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar('cookies.txt')
cookies.load(ignore_expires=True)

cert = ('cert','key')

m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'field': 'value'}
    )

headers = {
     'Content-Type': m.content_type,
}

r = requests.request('POST', url, data=m,
     headers=headers, cookies=cookies, cert=cert, verify=False)
```

From what I can i have matched all curl options. But as mentioned it seems to be ignoring the cookies, and tries to run a SSO. Any idea how to get this running? If nothing else works, I would have to run the curl via a subprocess. But i would rather get it going within the Python requests.

Any help/hints much appreciated.

Comment: Check `cookies` after you do the `.load()`.

Comment: Right, I should have checked on that earlier. There are required cookies, which are ignored. All of them have the following prefix ```#HttpOnly_```

Comment: So for the moment I have given up on the requests, and use subprocess to call curl. Was able to fix the cookies by reading the cookies into a dict, passing it into requests. But I had other issues with the request not working, mainly adding the fields in the POST request.